# How do I write a SQL (or dwSQL) query across these two different datasets?

Tags: data-mining, dataset, data, sql

I'm having a little fun and I'd love to know how to write a SQL or dwSQL query across these two datasets of Trumps tweets and Facebook posts. Here are the datasets:

**Trump Facebook Posts**
https://data.world/dave/trumps-facebook-statuses

**Trump Tweets**
https://data.world/dave/trump-tweets

Ideally I would like to be able to count the distinct instances that a word or phrase (like 'crooked' or 'massive' or 'the best' appeared across both datasets.

The table name for the Facebook Post dataset is `TrumpFacebook` and for the Trump Tweets is `trump_tweets`.

Comment: what kind of things have you tried so far?

Comment: Please add what you tried and which DB you are using for SQL since some syntax is different per DB.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this in SAS?

```
PROC SQL;
 CREATE TABLE TRUMP_FB_TWEETS AS
 SELECT *
 FROM TRUMP_FB
 UNION CORRESPONDING ALL
 SELECT *
 FROM TRUMP_TWEETS;
QUIT;
```

Source:http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi25/25/cc/25p109.pdf

Comment: Welcome to the Data science SO, the opp is asking for a SQL solution not SAS. Very few people have access to SAS so I would recommend to phrase this as a general SQL solution.

Comment: SAS University is a free download, but I can see your point.